# Outofmemoryerror in multithreading program

Tags: multithreading, jvm, websphere-liberty

I am writing a multithreading  application for Liberty JVM, the application using TCPIP communication open a socket, write to a socket and close socket, I am receiving closedChannel exception after OutOfMemmoryError error.

Question 1:
Did the closedChannel exception caused by Outofmemoryerror?

Question 2:
How to solve the issue ?

Comment: This page may help: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/4-general-reasons-outofmemoryerror-errors-and-how-not-get-fooled - it's specific to traditional WebSphere, but most of what it says also applies to Liberty. Another great resource is: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/knowledge-collection-out-memory-oom-websphere-application-server - this will help with question 2.  I wouldn't think that a closed channel exception would cause an OOM, but it's possible.  More likely, the native heap ran out of space due to too many threads and/or too many simultaneously open sockets.

Comment: How are you managing threads?  Since your app is running in a jakarta EE app server, you should obtain threads using jee standard means and not the same way a java SE app would do.